# jQuery - cannot access canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I cannot access a canvas element.

**Error**

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

**JS**

```
var canvas = $(".display");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jTH8p/1/)

Comment: jQuery exposes the actual DOM element in numeric indexes, where you can perform normal JavaScript/DOM functions

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `getContext()` (a [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial) method) on a jQuery object, not a `canvas` object.

Turn it back using `get(0)` like so:

```
var canvas = $(".display");
var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jTH8p/2/)